# Find Words in div class and save/print out

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to find the snapchat username of an instagram user. The div class is always the same and with an array I can loop more users. But to get the string of their snapchat is still an unsolved problem for me.

```
for i in range(len(Abonnenten)): #in my array 'Abonnenten' i got some urls of users
driver.get(Abonnenten[i]) #opens new tab of user everytime
# get the text from their instagram bio
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) #let the browser catch up, if internet is slow
    #This is to get the text of the bio. I never got any names to print out ever
    bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text
    #Snapnames = list.append(bio) #this was a try to get the names in a list so i can print all of names i found out
    #print(Snapnames)
    # check if text contains "snapchat" but i don´t think that works
    # also, can i add "snap" or "sc" to get a more results, because everyone puts their snap different in their bio
    if ("snapchat" in bio):

        # split the instagram bio by newline char to get line with snapchat name
        bio_lines = bio.split("\n")

        # parse over the instagram bio to find snapchat username, i dont get this line 
        for line in bio_lines:

            # if we find the line with username, strip out text to get the username
            if ("Snapchat:" in line):
                #snapchat_username = []
                snapchat_username = line.replace[("Snapchat:", "")]
                # you probably need to do something here to save to file
                print(snapchat_username)

    # case: the user does not have a bio, so just move on to the next one
except TimeoutException:
    continue
```

The main problem is, that I can´t get any snapchat names out of my programm.
Here is also a example how the user displays their snapchat name in their bio, because of that I want to include more words to search for in the bio.
[Snapchat name Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUGgi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I see comparing the screenshot to the code is that this Instagram user is denoting their Snapchat as `sc:` instead of `Snapchat:`, which is what the code is looking for. Username isn't getting found in the bio provided because code is checking for the presence of `snapchat` text (`if ("snapchat" in bio):`).

You will probably need to make a list of strings containing valid options for a user's snapchat username, such as `[ "snapchat:", "sc:", "snap:" ]` and check a user's bio against that list to see if their bio contains one of those strings -- if it does, then you can parse out the username.

```
bio = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='-vDIg']/span"))).text

# print bio to ensure we actually found something
print(bio)

# this should be moved above your for loop so it's not getting initialized every iteration
snapchat_strings = [ "snapchat:", "sc:", "snap:" ]

# iterate keywords list and check if user's bio has a keyword
for keyword in snapchat_strings:

    # check if user's bio has a snapchat keyword
    if (keyword in bio):
        bio_lines = bio.split("\n")

        # iterate lines in their bio to find the line with snapchat username
        for line in bio_lines:
            if (keyword in line):
                # case: we found SC username, so save it then break out of this loop
                snapchat_username = line.replace(keyword, "")
                print(snapchat_username)
```

When I provided my original solution to you, I did mention that writing a parser to find a Snapchat username correctly is quite difficult due to the various ways that users choose to denote their username in their bio. For example, if a user just writes down their Snapchat username, but they don't put "sc" or "snapchat" in front of it, then code will never be able to find that.

The other issue -- the bio lines might not be separated by a `\n` character, which would cause the line `bio_lines = bio.split("\n")` to not work properly. This may require some experimentation with the string printed out in `bio` to find the right separator.

Lastly -- your note above the line `for line in bio_lines:` means you'd probably like some explanation about how this works, so let me try to break this down.

Here's an example of someone's instagram bio:

```
Ex POINTER 
September 26
"tú, eres mis buenos dias"
snapchat:therock
```

Notice how this is broken up into 3 separate lines. I am making the assumption that these lines are broken up by the `\n` hidden character -- it's a form of whitespace that denotes a new line break. So we run `bio_lines = bio.split("\n")` to get a list of lines in their bio -- now, in code, the bio looks like this:

```
[ "Ex POINTER", "September 26", "\"tú, eres mis buenos dias\"", "snapchat:therock" ]
```

So we use a `for loop` to look at each item in this list, and check to see if it contains a snapchat username. That's what `for line in bio_lines:` is doing -- inside the loop, we check `if ("Snapchat:" in line):` -- this will return `true` when we reach the line `snapchat:therock`, and the idea is to parse out `snapchat:` so we just see `therock` printed on the console.